# jquery - using checkbox to allow for autofill

Tags: jquery

I have a popup box which contains a form with four input values and a checkbox. I want to make it that when the checkbox is checked, when one types his name in one check box it automatically begins typing him name in each of the other inputs. How would I accomplish this with jquery ajax? Are there any examples anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you can do something like below,

```
$("#txtbox").bind("keyup", function() {
    if ($("#CheckBox").attr("checked")) {
        $("#OtherTextBox1").val($(this).val());
        $("#OtherTextBox2").val($(this).val());
        $("#OtherTextBox3").val($(this).val());
    }
});
```

Hope this Helps!!

Comment: Would this really work without ajax? Does the OtherTextBox1 etc really have a value for val() if it was just inputed right now? I'm starting with a blank form.

Comment: yes it does, this just fetches the value (from the attribute value) and inserts it into the other elements

Answer (score 0):

Here's an a quick idea to sync changes across all inputs to each other.

http://jsfiddle.net/kQaXm/2/

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
<input type="input" id="input1" />
<input type="input" id="input2" />
<input type="input" id="input3" /> 
<input type="input" id="input4" />

$(function(){
    var $inputs =  $('input[id^=input]');
    $inputs.keyup( function(){
        if( $('#checkbox').is(':checked') )
            $inputs.val( this.value );
    });
});
```

Comment: And for the follow up question: I mentioned that this is a popup box, which means that these inputs don't exist at the creation of the dom. So, I need to use .delegate() not ready(). How do I do that? Do I only need to pass the checkbox selector to delegate() because thats the thing the event is on?

Comment: That means that it's looking for inputs that start with an id of 'input', so it doesn't matter what comes after 'input', it will still match.

Comment: @user1015214 This one will work if they're added dynamically. You may need to adjust the .on binding to apply to your situation. http://jsfiddle.net/kQaXm/3/

Comment: I don't understand your code. What is 'on' doing (i've never used that function), is it really fixing my issue? To clarify: the values I put in the input box are dynamic (by definition, since I am entering them), its just that the popup box doesn't exist when you first start the page. And thats why your code works on jsfiddle but not on my page (yet.)

Comment: [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is the current `.delegate()`/`.live()` method. Its entire reason for existing is dealing with things not in the dom on document ready. The actions bubble up the dom, so you bind the capture to an element which will always be present. In the case of this fiddle, it's the wrapper around the checkbox, in your case, it will be what ever element to which you append the popup.